# How to prevent nested queries in sqlalchemy from selecting a table again?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I wrote a query for mysql that achieved what I wanted. It's structured a bit like this:

```
select * from table_a where exists(
  select * from table_b where table_a.x = table_b.x and exists(
    select * from table_c where table_a.y = table_c.y and table_b.z = table_c.z
  )
)
```

I translated the query to sqlalchemy and the result is structured like this:

```
session.query(table_a).filter(
  session.query(table_b).filter(table_a.x == table_b.x).filter(
    session.query(table_c).filter(table_a.y == table_c.y).filter(table_b.x == table_c.z).exists()
  ).exists()
)
```

Which generates a query like this:

```
select * from table_a where exists(
  select * from table_b where table_a.x = table_b.x and exists(
    select * from table_c, table_a where table_a.y = table_c.y and table_b.z = table_c.z
  )
)
```

Note the re-selection of `table_a` in the innermost query - which breaks the intended functionality.

How can I stop sqlalchemy from selecting the table again in a nested query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell the innermost query to [correlate all except `table_c`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.correlate_except):

```
session.query(table_a).filter(
  session.query(table_b).filter(table_a.x == table_b.x).filter(
    session.query(table_c).filter(table_a.y == table_c.y).filter(table_b.x == table_c.z)
    .exists().correlate_except(table_c)
  ).exists()
)
```

In contrast to "auto-correlation", which only considers FROM elements from the enclosing [`Select`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select), [explicit correlation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.correlate) will consider FROM elements from any nesting level as candidates.